# How to increase and decrease value with seekBar within range

Tags: android, progress, seekbar

```
int a = 1000;

int b = 2000;
```

So when seekBar slider is all the way right, `int a is 2000`, and all the way left, int a is 1000.

If I try something like this:

```
int a = a + seekBar.getProgress();
```

I get infinite increment of int a...

Comment: What do you mean?  That you are looping over that call an infinite number of times?  If so, you need to provide the relevant code that is doing the work.

Comment: Use `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener` to get the value in seekbar. based on its value you can calculate value of a.